# Traversing through Word document using Office JS

Tags: javascript, angular, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I'm working on a Word Add-in using Angular, and I'm stuck at this point here.
I'm trying to traverse through the document searching for occurences of a word, but instead of performing an operation on all occurrences, I want to perform an operation on them by navigating to them and determine what to do with them one by one.

I have the following code:

```
    goToNext(searchString: string){
        return Word.run(wordContext => {

            var results = wordContext.document.body.search(searchString, { matchWholeWord: true, matchCase: true });      //Search for the text to replace
            results.getFirst().select();
            return wordContext.sync();
        });
    }
```

This does select the first occurrence of the search, but calling the function again won't select the next occurrence.

How do I go to the next occurrence by calling that method again?

Comment: Why would you not loop `results`? And there would be no need to *select* each instance. Do you mean to pass "control" to the user for each "hit", then continue from there? And `searchString` is not being altered by the user action? In that case, you'd need to use a `range` that extends from the current selection to the end-point of the document, rather than running each search on the entire document.

Comment: Yes, control should be passed for each "hit". I checked the code, and somebody had already made a way to deal with this. Calling `results.items[index].select();` helped me with my problem. The index value just needs to be incremented here.

A full working example:
`Word.run(wordContext => {
const search = wordContext.document.body.search(query);
wordContext.load(search);
return wordContext.sync().then(() => {
search.items[index].select();
});
`

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this in a comment, but marking this as the answer for others that might be interested

```
Word.run(wordContext => {
        const search = wordContext.document.body.search(searchTerm, { matchWholeWord: wholeWord, matchCase: true });
        wordContext.load(search);
        return wordContext.sync().then(() => {
            search.items[index].select();
        });
```

This selects the word that is searched for based on where it is located in document reading the index value

Answer (score 0):

Use Below function to search for a particular text under word document, make sure to pass **correct wordIndex** present under document for the word you would like to search

```
goToNext(searchString: string, wordIndex : string){
    Word.run(async function(wordContext) {
            var results = wordContext.document.body.search(searchString, { matchWholeWord: true, matchCase: true });      //Search for the text to replace
            context.load(results);
            return context.sync().then(() => {
        search.items[wordIndex].font.highlightColor = '#ffedcc'; //If you want to highlight the selection with background color
                search.items[wordIndex].select();
            });
        });
    }
```